# How to handle irregular time series charting

Tags: javascript, typescript, charts, statistics, echarts

I have some data I'm getting from an api and graphing it. [This is a sample of the data](https://pastebin.com/cs3EdryH)

```
[
    {
        "id": 10516560,
        "username": "acrawford69",
        "avatar_url": "https://a.ppy.sh/10516560?1661994504.png",
        "country_code": "US",
        "country": {
            "code": "US",
            "name": "United States"
        },
        "cover_url": "https://assets.ppy.sh/user-profile-covers/10516560/a48a1388412e00cb53f63a18c988460f3a823bc59abfbca57dc0f3178518f828.jpeg",
        "playstyle": [
            "keyboard",
            "tablet"
        ],
        "stats": [
            {
                "count300": 125059,
                "count100": 26906,
                "count50": 5572,
                "playcount": 1492,
                "ranked_score": "103758885",
                "total_score": "351690963",
                "pp_rank": 483837,
                "level": 37.7535,
                "pp_raw": 376.591,
                "accuracy": 90.7366943359375,
                "count_rank_ss": 2,
                "count_rank_s": 40,
                "count_rank_a": 60,
                "timestamp": "2018-01-01T14:05:19Z"
            },
            {
                "count300": 1402229,
                "count100": 222088,
                "count50": 23084,
                "playcount": 13221,
                "ranked_score": "1270502397",
                "total_score": "5646827189",
                "pp_rank": 113169,
                "level": 92.9875,
                "pp_raw": 2119.61,
                "accuracy": 95.52465057373047,
                "count_rank_ss": 21,
                "count_rank_s": 244,
                "count_rank_a": 315,
                "timestamp": "2018-04-19T10:39:30Z"
            },
            {
                "count300": 2790003,
                "count100": 402271,
                "count50": 36326,
                "playcount": 23752,
                "ranked_score": "2276685904",
                "total_score": "12164504933",
                "pp_rank": 54358,
                "level": 97.8885,
                "pp_raw": 3174.39,
                "accuracy": 95.93881225585938,
                "count_rank_ss": 24,
                "count_rank_s": 333,
                "count_rank_a": 467,
                "timestamp": "2018-07-12T15:55:55Z"
            },
                        {
                "count300": 3247631,
                "count100": 476426,
                "count50": 42776,
                "playcount": 27152,
                "ranked_score": "2524961796",
                "total_score": "14635199169",
                "pp_rank": 47794,
                "level": 98.4106,
                "pp_raw": 3403.8,
                "accuracy": 95.63449096679688,
                "count_rank_ss": 26,
                "count_rank_s": 347,
                "count_rank_a": 491,
                "timestamp": "2018-07-30T16:01:46Z"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 9683580,
        "username": "Vynxica",
        "avatar_url": "https://a.ppy.sh/9683580?1671751072.jpeg",
        "country_code": "HR",
        "country": {
            "code": "HR",
            "name": "Croatia"
        },
        "cover_url": "https://assets.ppy.sh/user-profile-covers/9683580/97a293b985f6fb3764559f579dccfdd23aa43596d36efadcfdacfbca917dc0d8.gif",
        "playstyle": [
            "keyboard",
            "tablet"
        ],
        "stats": [
            {
                "count300": 1145788,
                "count100": 131699,
                "count50": 10432,
                "playcount": 11833,
                "ranked_score": "917770565",
                "total_score": "5786130619",
                "pp_rank": 93095,
                "level": 93.308,
                "pp_raw": 2391.06,
                "accuracy": 97.15504455566406,
                "count_rank_ss": 13,
                "count_rank_s": 142,
                "count_rank_a": 140,
                "timestamp": "2018-04-15T19:10:20Z"
            },
            {
                "count300": 1167625,
                "count100": 133033,
                "count50": 10455,
                "playcount": 12002,
                "ranked_score": "931440095",
                "total_score": "5939756779",
                "pp_rank": 91215,
                "level": 93.6577,
                "pp_raw": 2429.73,
                "accuracy": 97.23928833007812,
                "count_rank_ss": 13,
                "count_rank_s": 147,
                "count_rank_a": 138,
                "timestamp": "2018-04-17T20:40:28Z"
            },
            {
                "count300": 1285778,
                "count100": 142285,
                "count50": 10715,
                "playcount": 13141,
                "ranked_score": "984832452",
                "total_score": "6614981180",
                "pp_rank": 83540,
                "level": 94.8007,
                "pp_raw": 2578.79,
                "accuracy": 97.06028747558594,
                "count_rank_ss": 13,
                "count_rank_s": 162,
                "count_rank_a": 138,
                "timestamp": "2018-05-04T09:35:20Z"
            },
            {
                "count300": 1418779,
                "count100": 153004,
                "count50": 11125,
                "playcount": 14369,
                "ranked_score": "1067690803",
                "total_score": "7441652978",
                "pp_rank": 65121,
                "level": 95.6683,
                "pp_raw": 2751.09,
                "accuracy": 97.38233184814453,
                "count_rank_ss": 13,
                "count_rank_s": 166,
                "count_rank_a": 150,
                "timestamp": "2018-05-19T19:48:10Z"
            },
        ]
    }
```

I can get it to graph fine, but I would like to make it so that when looking at the data, the tooltip displays the data for the closest point, even if it is quite far away. [For instance, I would like it to display the date from the nearby point on the green line as well.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDbBY.png) I'm open to switching chart libraries, currently I am using echarts.

I have tried writing a custom tooltip function that searches for the closest value on each line and displaying it, but I could not get it working. At all.

Answer (score 0):

I made a small [example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-smooth&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWsAeBBDEDOAXMgL4A0asAnjvkUmRWMMADaQh0XoBmwATgFsAhmDABTPkQDmYsADkxQvmLxhy6BujwSIKogG0uyI-gAmIoQf0AGUgA4ATNYC6pWPoCMpAJwBmB67uvj7WHoH6AKw-vgAs4QDspB4O3i5u-t5Jvr5p7slZTs6uJrBglCBiRADkLBDQYlXq6M14AsxgABZEYHwArmJGms2ozc3mYJbuNqS-AGzx4Q6k8anhMSER4bOkMdbe4XZJKbmeth7ZJ_kR1nHFo-hlFdW19Y0lre1dpX0Do8QUzhQxAA3CgUNxetAAMaQGCwGTyRTKVQAChASiEAjwAEpjOgoTBVLBtHxdHgAJLQUxiDAIWDoviYvAAOhJZMp1IwoPxhLAmAAakIWP06QymcyAG5C_o2Zzc2AsWSwKG9PgAeXAUDgiAElAAwh0lGBmQiNbDoCjsfLFXzkb02HSAEQAHlMEAlAD5HbAANT0jFYyXSsSy32wb3ev1iwNS4UhsJhl0Aejdnsd8oovD4sBRNtgdU5-bgKvVmpgrJ0KlxI2aEG4OYLNIQiDZKg5NOrJQJ0Eg0H68o0RiM3aJrbwdJLZq1FdJKn0jYwcqMefqShUYAAGnTKdw6hAygOFUrV8iwABNQ9ZnN58ZCEDAOp84D1sfM2-d-75-sogCyIg6zJCAARngKK3vej6hgAtAKwa4s6iB_p0gEgSiJ7rluMEYIKcbYh-n6wOhqhbog4EPj2sqHqMRHnnSZGQWEVGwP8fxGHaDo-ogLqpl6YY0VufoRnxSLrmeibOim7pehQLGwBQyhgKqcDsWAoLEEAA) illustrating how it could be done in echarts. Depending on how your data is given to the series you might have to make some small changes. Currently the closest x-value is taken as the closest point. Also the formatting is very barebones but I hope you can take it from here.

Code:

```js
option = {
  xAxis: {},
  yAxis: {},
  tooltip: {
    formatter: getNearest,
  },
  series: [
    {
      data: [[0,820], [1,932], [3,901], [5,934], [7,1290], [9,1330], [12,1320]],
      type: 'line',
      smooth: true
    },
    {
      data: [[0,367], [2,790], [4,905], [6,409], [8,1290], [10,1330], [12,504]],
      type: 'line',
      smooth: true
    }
  ]
};

function getNearest(params) {
  const seriesIndex = params.seriesIndex;
  const xValue = params.value[0];
  let curOption = myChart.getOption();
  let result = "<div>" + params.value[0] + " " + params.value[1] + "</div>";
  
  for (let index in curOption.series) {
    if (index == seriesIndex) {
      continue;
    }
    
    const series = curOption.series[index];
    let nearestX = Infinity;
    let nearestY;
    for (let datapoint of series.data) {
      if (Math.abs(datapoint[0] - xValue) <= Math.abs(nearestX - xValue)) {
        nearestX = datapoint[0];
        nearestY = datapoint[1];
      }
    }
    result += "<div>" + nearestX + " " + nearestY + "</div>"
  }
  
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this is similar what to what I tried. I think the issue is the x-axis for my chart is type: 'time'. Trying your formatter function, I get an error "undefined is not an object" on this line: 
    const xValue = params.value[0];

Time type seems to not be user-friendly

Comment: I think this has to do with the fact that you provide your data in a different format. If you just use axis type 'time' in my example there is no error. You can try `console.log(params)` in the formatter function to look at the structure of the data and adjust the function accordingly.

Comment: If you are using a dataset for example, the data object is a dictionary and not an array. Or you can provide x-values with the `xAxis` and only the y-values in the series.